# Open graph (og:) meta tags not working in my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am working with og: meta tags. I have written 3-4 meta tags in my website, but when i share it on facebook it does not display the information i have provided in the tags. This is my [Website](http://www.bitbayofficial.com) when i share it on facebook, and the facebook fetches the data, then the meta tags does not work. I do not know whats the problem. Below are the screen shot of the facebook result. And it displays the default **Material design startup template**. And by default shows the site title name.

**The meta tags in my website**

```js
<meta property="og:title" content="Antesoft Technologies" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Antesoft, A new future.">
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.bitbayofficial.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://jackfitzgerald.com/jack1/wp-content/uploads/robotwrite1-760x360.jpg" />
```

**The Result**

[image]

Comment: Please try to share again and see if your desired values appear.

Comment: Solved : I have not added this - xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved : I have not added this  in the HTML tag.

```js
xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```